# Memory Management while embedding python in C# using python.net

Tags: python.net, python-embedding

I am trying to understand how memory is managed when python is embedded in C# using python.net. Python is executed in C# using the `py.GIL` (global interpreter lock), essentially C# calls the python interpreter and executes the python code. What I don't understand is how is memory allocated and deallocated for python objects.

I couldn't find anything online and any type of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# `PyObject` is holding a Python object handle (which are pointers into C heap). Internally Python objects count references to themselves.

In C# you can either force releasing the handle by calling `PyObject.Dispose`, in which case Python object refcount is decreased immediately, and if at this point it reaches 0, Python object will be destroyed and deallocated (from C heap).

Alternatively, wait until `PyObject` instance is collected by .NET garbage collector. When that happens, the Python object handle is added to an internal queue, which is periodically emptied when you create new `PyObject`s (e.g. `PyObject` constructor will go check that queue, and release all handles in it).

This applies to Python.NET 2.5 and the upcoming 3.0.

Comment: Is the PyObject created when you initialize python in C#? Also, you mentioned internally python objects count references to themselves, are they decreased/ deleted immediately by python's garbage collector when an object has 0 references?

Comment: Initializing python in C# creates many `PyObject`. Every object you receive from Python is also wrapped in `PyObject`.

Comment: As for deletion, as soon as there are 0 references to a Python object,  it is deleted. There's a separate procedure in Python, that deletes reference cycles.